# Access scope in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript

I have the below code, and have been trying and been reading and yet cant figure out how to loop over the params array/object, and set the key value pairs on to 'this' so I can access them as per the last line in my below code.

I believe it is because of the scope, that 'this' doesnt refer to my function anymore when it is in the for loop, but how can I get the scope in there? I found that you can add it as a secondary parameter to a foreach loop, but I can not get a foreach loop working over an associate array.....

I would like to be able to access any value in the array passed to the function batman, later on, in the way my example shows to print out lname.

```js
function batman(id,params){
  this.id=id;
  for(.....params.....){
    // this.key=val;
  }
  
}


x=new batman("my_id",{fname:"jason",lname:"bourne"});
console.log("id: "+x.id); // works fine
console.log("fname: "+x.fname); // would like to get this to work...
```

Comment: `this` *never* refers to your function; it refers to the newly-created object. You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the parameter object properties into the new object.  However you can also use a `for ... in` loop, which will not affect the value of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this? It seems like your issue is in parsing the key/value pairs in the `params` object. Run the snippet to see it work...

```js
function batman(id,params){
  this.id=id;
  for(var key in params){
    this[key]=params[key];
  }
}


x=new batman("my_id",{fname:"jason",lname:"bourne"});
console.log("id: "+x.id); // works fine
console.log("fname: "+x.fname); // hey look! this works fine now...
```

Comment: ah! i used this.key and not this[key] . Much appreciated!

Comment: To add to the answer: `key` in the loop is a string. So you need to wrap the `key` in square bracket to assign it. What you are doing is assigning value to `x.key`. so if you `console.log(x.key)` you'll see the value of the last loop there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forEach` on the keys of `params` in order to set the properties of this.

I've updated `batman` to `Batman`, for the sake of sticking to convention.

```js
function Batman(id,params){
  this.id=id;
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => this[key] = params[key])
}


x=new Batman("my_id",{fname:"jason",lname:"bourne"});
console.log("id: "+x.id); // works fine
console.log("fname: "+x.fname); // would like to get this to work...
```